# Sumar dígitos de un número en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Necesito un código en js para sumar los dígitos de un número. Por ejemplo, en 56, quiero que sume el 5 y el 6. Gracias de antemano ;-)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Te invito a que conozcas como funciona la comunidad visitando la [presentación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). A continuación, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta siguiendo las [directrices de calidad](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Como verás SO.es no es un sustituto de Google; la investigación y los intentos van por tu cuenta. Por otro lado ¿Podrías añadir más información a la Pregunta? _"Qué has intentado"_, como, código de ejemplo.  De esta manera se te podrá brindar una mejor respuesta.

Comment: Prueba con `console.log(11);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como dice @amenadiel, debes usar un mayor contexto al expresar tu pregunta (¿cuál es tu entorno?, ¿cuál es la versión de ECMAScript que estás usando?, ¿qué es lo que intentas resolver?, etc.); sin embargo, aventuro una respuesta al problema:

```
var x = "56";
var y = 0;
x.split('').forEach(x => y += parseInt(x));
```

El resultado: `y = 11`.

O como una función (aunque no se valida la entrada, pues podría incluir caracteres no numéricos):

```
function sumaString(entrada) {
  let res = 0;
  entrada.split('').forEach(c => res += parseInt(c));
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta. No te preocupes con la validación. Usaré un regexp ;-)

Comment: Ten en cuenta que estoy usando sintaxis ES6 (por ejemplo let y =>), así que debes tener cuidado con eso (en base a dónde será ejecutado esto). [Aquí](https://es6console.com/j04hnqv5/) puedes ver el código transformado a ES5, más estándar.

Comment: Perfe. Gracias y sobre todo, te agradezco que me hayas dado ideas para contextualizar la pregunta. Gracias a ti sabré cómo preguntar las próximas veces

Comment: Acabo de probar el script y me devuelve NaN. Como habrás notado, soy un poco mucho novato y no sé que puedo hacer para que me salga un número válido. Podrías mirar el script y reenviármelo revisao?

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu cadena de entrada? NaN significa "Not a Number" (no es un número) y se retorna cuando intentas procesar algo que no es un número usando una función que requiere números (que en este caso es la función parseInt()); por ejemplo si tu cadena usa decimales (3.1415) ya no funcionaría porque la función "intentará" sumar el símbolo de punto ("."), cosa que no es posible.

Comment: Gracias, pero ya no tiene importancia. Ya no necesito el script :(

Answer (score 2):

Usando código recursivo:

```js
var sumarDigitos = function(num) {
  if(0<num) {
    return (num%10) + sumarDigitos(Math.floor(num/10));
  }
  return num;
};

alert(sumarDigitos(1111111111));//10
```

No se si es el mejor rendimiento, pero pues es una opción para practicar conceptos de recursión.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias hacer lo siguiente:

- Conviertes el `number` a `string` usando [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toString).
- Luego generas un `array` separando cada uno de los números, usando [`.split('')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split)
- Por último, queda iterar el `array` y sumar cada uno de los valores, usando [`.reduce(fn)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce);

Ejemplo:

```js
var number = 56;
console.log(number.toString().split('').reduce(function(r, n) { return r + parseInt(n) }, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya que todos tiraron respuesta, aquí va la mia:

```
function sumadigitos(numero) {
  var formato_string=String(numero),
      transforma_array=formato_string.split(''),
      suma_digitos=transforma_array.reduce(function(valorAnterior, valorActual, indice, vector){
          return 1*valorAnterior + (isNaN(1*valorActual)? 0: 1*valorActual);
      },0);
  return suma_digitos;
}
```

Lo que hace esta función es

- Transforma el parámetro a string
- Lo explota, convirtiéndolo a array, carácter por carácter
- Al array así obtenido, le aplica el método [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)
- En cada iteración de reduce, comprueba si el siguiente carácter es no numérico (en cuyo caso vale 0) o numérico.
- Entrega el resultado del reduce.

```js
function sumadigitos(numero) {
   var formato_string=String(numero),
       transforma_array=formato_string.split(''),
       suma_digitos=transforma_array.reduce(function(valorAnterior, valorActual, indice, vector){
           return 1*valorAnterior + (isNaN(1*valorActual)? 0: 1*valorActual);
       },0);
  return suma_digitos;
}

console.log(sumadigitos(56));

console.log(sumadigitos('12a3'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, la pregunta ya esta respondida perfectamente, pero voy a abstraerme un poquito y voy a plantear el algoritmo. por que lo considero material de estudio.

Todos asumieron que hablabamos de numeros enteros y supongamos que si. Tambien supongamos que nuestro Tipo Abstracto de Datos "Entero" admite las operaciones basicas suma, resta, multiplicacion (notese que la division no es cerrada para los enteros asi que no podemos usarla, y la potencia solo es mas multiplicación)

Dado un numero entero "x" podemos expresarlo como potencias de 10:

a0.10^0 + a1.10^1 + ... +ap.10^p donde (a0 + a1 + ... + ap) es el resultado que buscamos.

¿Como calcular "p"?. Bueno la idea es buscar potencias de 10 menores al numero dado.

```
var p = 0
DO (x > 10^p)
  p = p + 1
OD
```

una vez encontrado "p" el siguiente paso es contar cuantas unidades, cuantas decenas, centenas y asi. Para esto vamos a anidar dos "while" (DO en pseudo-código) para que por cada "p" cuente las unidades:

```
var R = 0 // aqui va el resultado final
var u = 0 // Nuestro contador de unidades
var y = x // Vamos decreciendo osea ap + ap-1 +...+ a1 + a0
DO (p > 0)
  DO (y > 10^p)
    u = u + 1
    y = y - 10^p
  OD
  p = p -1
OD
R = u + y // en "y" quedan las unidades menores que 10
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function sumar(valor)
    {
        var suma=0;
        for(var i=0;i<valor.length;i++)
        {
            suma+=parseInt(valor[i]);
        }
        document.getElementById("resultadoSuma").innerHTML="La Suma de los valores de "+valor+" es: "+suma;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<input name="numeros" type="text" id="text" onkeyup="sumar(this.value);">
<div id="resultadoSuma"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor actualiza tu respuesta, explicando cómo tu código responde a la pregunta del OP. Mira esta guía de [cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).